# OpenLayers Raster Reprojection to Mollweide cropped to oval

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, proj4js

I'm trying to setup a Mollweide map, and only see a single projection of the world. Without the doubly projected areas in the corners of the map (see included images for clarification). Is there a technique that achieves this?

See the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7901arop/150/

###### Wanted result

[image] [image: Wanted result]

###### Actually achieved results

[image: Achieved results]

I added the Graticule to better visualise what part of the map I want to show, and what part of the map has to be cropped / hidden / covered / ....

In the right picture i set the `wrapX` option of the `OSM` source to `false`, which comes close to a possible solution but introduces other weird artefacts.

###### Current implementation

```
//Setup layers
const streetMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM({
    wrapX: true,
    //wrapX: false   
    
    /* If set to false, it acomplishes 
       the wanted effect on the west side 
       of the globe, but not on the east side  */
  })
})
const Graticule = new ol.layer.Graticule({targetSize: 30})




//Setup Projection
proj4.defs('ESRI:54009', '+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 units=m +no_defs');
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
const sphereMollweideProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'ESRI:54009',
  extent: [-18019909.21177587, -9009954.605703328, 18019909.21177587, 9009954.605703328],
  worldExtent: [-179.99, -89.99, 179.99, 89],
});



//Set map on the screen
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [streetMap, Graticule],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: sphereMollweideProjection,
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0.5
  })
});
```

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks for the heads up. I edited the question to include my current implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use vector clipping similar to this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping-vector.html

Instead of a feature for Switzerland create a polygon for the visible world

```
var coordinates = [];
for (var i = 90; i >= -90; --i) {
  coordinates.push([-179.99, i * 0.9999]);
}
for (var i = -90; i <= 90; ++i) {
  coordinates.push([179.99, i * 0.9999]);
}
coordinates.push(coordinates[0]);

var clip = new ol.geom.Polygon([coordinates]).transform('EPSG:4326', sphereMollweideProjection);

var style = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'black'
  })
});

streetMap.on('postrender', function (e) {
  var vectorContext = ol.render.getVectorContext(e);
  e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  vectorContext.setStyle(style);
  vectorContext.drawGeometry(clip);
  e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f2013vy9/

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for, also thanks for the elaborate answer!